# Displaying Image in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I put the `must.jpg` in `drawable-hdpi` folder and created this method.

```
public void createImageViewOb (){
        File poster = new File ("/BakuMovies/res/drawable-hdpi/must.jpg");
        ImageView poster_view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.drawable.must);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(poster.getAbsolutePath());
        poster_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

I want to display image on the screen by calling this method in `mainActivity`

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        createImageViewOb ();
    }
```

But when I launch app it crashes. 
I will appreciate any help.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="77dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textSwitcher1"
        android:text="@string/Albert"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/aboutMeButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/viewFlipper1"
        android:onClick="showAboutMessage"
        android:text="About Me" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

LogCat:

```
02-22 05:13:29.028: E/Trace(1145): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-22 05:13:29.498: D/AndroidRuntime(1145): Shutting down VM
02-22 05:13:29.498: W/dalvikvm(1145): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bakumovies/com.example.bakumovies.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.example.bakumovies.MainActivity.createImageViewOb(MainActivity.java:44)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at com.example.bakumovies.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
02-22 05:13:29.518: E/AndroidRuntime(1145):     ... 11 more
02-22 05:13:31.449: I/Process(1145): Sending signal. PID: 1145 SIG: 9
```

Comment: please paste your logcat

Comment: What is the error? Use logcat to get the full stack trace and post it here.

Comment: Also, please post `activity_main.xml`.

Comment: Since your image is in one of the drawable folders, you can not access it as a file. Your file object would be null and that's why your app is crashing.

Comment: The easiest way to do this would be `poster_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.must);`

Comment: Why are you crawling when you can run...

Answer (score 2):

There are so many things you could avoid and very easily load the image you want into the `ImageView`.

Do something like this:-

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // New Code
        ImageView poster_view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView); //Assuming an ImgView is there in your layout activity_main
        poster_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.must); //Must.jpg present in any of your drawable folders.
    }
```

***Update:-*** To insert an `ImageView` dynamically, do this in your `onCreate()`.

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);        
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.must);        
yourLinearLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Comment: What if I haven't described must.jpg in activity_main? Is there any method to show image without predescribing it in activity_main before launch of app?

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that the Android device will most likely not have a directory named `/BakuMovies/res/drawable-hdpi`. This is the directory structure of your development environment and is *not* directly transferred to the device. Other than that, I cannot give without knowing what you are trying to do.

**Edit:**

Note that all the resources in your `res` directory are included in your app's .APK file. They are not loaded to the device as individual files. In order to access resources (other than strings) in Java code, you need to use a [`Resources`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html) object. You get one by calling  [`getResources()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29) on an `Activity` object. Once you have the `Resources` object, call [`getDrawable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawable%28int%29) or [`getDrawableForDensity()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDrawableForDensity%28int,%20int%29) to get a drawable resource.

Comment: I want method to display image on the main screen of application, without describing it in activity_main.xml before launch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public void createImageViewOb (){

        ImageView poster_view = (ImageView)findViewById((R.id.imageView); // imageView is id of your imageView

        poster_view.setImageResource(R.drawable.must);
}
```

**Updated**

First you have to add `ImageView`  on your `activity_main` layout and set its `id` as `android:id="@+id/imageView"`.

Answer (score 0):

You used drawable. You call setImageDrawable method and than set resource getResources ().getDrawable set id getdrawable method than image will be showing.

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause is that your application is running out of memory while trying to decode the image in the line below

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(poster.getAbsolutePath());
```

What are the dimensions of this image that you are trying to load?

Comment: Dimensions of the picture - 231x330.

Comment: Please see my comment in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your activity you can call this to get your Drawable resource as a Drawable object and set the image as below:

```
     Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.must);
     ImageView poster_view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView));
      poster_view.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

OR

If you want to show your drawable in an ImageView you can do this:

```
    ImageView poster_view = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    poster_view.setImageResource(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.must));
```

or in your xml file

```
 <ImageView   
     android:id="@+id/imageView" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/smiley"/>
```

Comment: I have updated my code and solved the faulty issue. Please now revoke your down vote R.J. Thanks